# Can I prevent iOS closing email compose window, losing user data

Tags: ios, email, memory

I have a group email app where customers create emails in a standard iOS compose window. If they write a long email, then switch apps to do a memory intensive task, iOS may close the compose window, losing the contents of their email.

Is there a way to prevent the window being closed? or a way to ensure iOS saves the email to drafts before closing it?

I am wondering if I am not retaining a link that I should be, perhaps?

Can anyone else confirm whether they see the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to understand the [App Life Cycle on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html).

When the App is running in background, the method `applicationWillTerminate` will be called, this is one of your options to save the content of the email. But this method is not called every time, it is only called when your app isn't suspended or when the user reboots his device.

One solution is to save this data inside the method `applicationDidEnterBackground`, it is called as soon as your app starts to run in background. And reload the data inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, this allows you to perform any final initialization before your app is displayed to the user.

Comment: I do save the data which belongs to my app, such as groups of email addresses, when I go into the background. However I believe developers have no access to the contents of an iOS email compose window (presumably for privacy reasons) so I could not save that as I don’t know what it contains. Is there a method of accessing or saving that data which I’m not aware of?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get this data, but I think you are right, this data is not accessible to developers for privacy reasons. If this data was available I believe it should be inside the `mailComposeController(_:didFinishWith:error:)` method

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent the window being closed? or a way to ensure iOS saves the email to drafts before closing it?

There's nothing you can do to prevent the window from being closed, because iOS is killing the app. What you can do is to save the email at some point before that happens. Since the user obviously can't modify the email while the app is in the background, saving the message when the app goes into the background would be a good choice. That way, you'll have the data saved if iOS does end up killing the app, and you can check to see if there's a saved message that needs to be restored when the app launches.

If you take that approach, though, you'll also have to figure out a way to help the user get back to their saved message, which means that you also need to keep track of how they got there in the first place so you can recreate that state. If it's just a simple message, maybe all you need to do is to open a message editor view and set it up with the saved message. In general, though, this can be a thorny problem. Luckily, Apple has provided a nice solution...

The *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS* has a section called [*Preserving and Restoring State*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH28-SW1), which explains how you can set your app up to automatically save and restore its state. With a relatively small amount of work, you can set your app up so that the user will never even notice that the app has restarted -- if they launch it after iOS has killed it, the app will recreate the view controllers so that it looks like the app was running the whole time, even if the device was shut down in the interim.

Comment: I don’t believe a developer can access the contents of an email compose window, so I am unable to save it when the app moves to the background (as I do with the user’s group data, for instance)